# Does SQLite have some kind of pragma or special query for determining which record was added last?

Tags: logging, sqlite

I need to locate the last record inserted into a SQLite table quickly. The table doesn't have any kind of timestamps or record ids as it is meant to mirror an output log in realtime. As the data grows larger it may be a problem to navigate to the last record to retrieve it.

It is not possible to add and timestamp records or ids to it as any mismatch between the logging configuration and the table structure will break the logging code.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you have not explicitly added an [autoincrementing column](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html), the table will still have the internal [rowid column](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid):

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable ORDER BY rowid DESC LIMIT 1;
```